# Problem using Semi-automatic classification plugin on QGIS for downloading Sentinel-2 images

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, download, sentinel-2

I´m trying to use the Semi-automatic classification plugin on QGIS 2.14.3 for downloading Sentinel-2 images. No secret following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoHSlKfSiCE&feature=youtu.be. But I don´t know why, does not work. **Error [50]: Internet error.**

Comment: It is mentioned in the comments for that video that there were issues accessing the data: [Sentinel-2 Download Issues Using the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin: Solved](http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2016/06/sentinel-2-download-issues.html). It does provide a possible solution you could try.

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me, using the URL https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you have already found the solution.
I had some problems with this plugin and i changed the service URL to `https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/`.

Comment: Amazing - this fixed it for me